# Find the color to start the sequence

Tags: word-sequence

What color should begin the following sequence of words?

- ***???***
- fruit
- letter
- computer
- number
- subject
- consume
- before
- cut
- cry
- slide
- gentle
- awake
- not
- rain
- cold

#### Hint 1

> Beneath the sequence is a ring of other words.

#### Hint 2

> That ring can be found by looking at pairs of the sequence.

#### Hint 3

> Each pair is made of words adjacent to each other in the sequence.

#### Hint 4

> The ring has eight words.

#### Hint 5

> Each word in the ring is connected to its neighbors through their initial letters.

Comment: Blue! No, yellooaaaaaaaahhhh!

Comment: can we get another hint?

Comment: I was sure it was pairs! Fruit & computer -> apple and number & consume -> 8/ate, right?

Comment: I bet its Orange!

Comment: Do all pairs of the sequence have a word that is part of the ring?

Answer (score 4):

I'm totally wild guessing here:

> Scarlet

Because:

> It seems to me that by adjacent we should consider words that are "connected" via another word. That is, not the words x and x+1, but x-1 and x+1. So for example we pair "letter" and "number" and get "symbol"

So, we get a partial solution for some of the words:

> **scarlet**
> fruit - A (scarlet letter)
> letter - apple
> computer - symbol
> number
> subject - consumer
> consume - history
> before - 
> cut - happy
> cry - 
> slide - weep
> gentle -
> awake - rough
> not - 
> rain - hot
> cold -

We basically need to find a color:

> the color must fit with rain and letter. So I'm guessing **scarlet** for: "scarlet rain" (because of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_rain) or perhaps blood in general) and the [The Scarlet Letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scarlet_Letter), which is the letter "A".

Comment: You're on the right track, but the second paragraph is incorrect; adjacent means what it sounds like.

Answer (score 1):

partial answer - maybe you can help me getting the missing pieces :-)

building the word ring

> ??? and fruit
>
>  letter and computer -> email
>
>  number and subject 
>
>  consume and before -> expiration date
>
>  cut and cry -> onions
>
>  slide and gentle -> adults only ;-)
>
>  awake and not -> sleeping
>
>  rain and cold -> november

Suggestions for the color:

> black or blue
>
>  because, if it is connected with the fruit to build a word, I am thinking of Blueberry or Blackberry (this may also fit with the email, if you think of the Blackberry phones)

Comment: You have the correct idea, and you're correct for "letter and computer" and almost correct for "awake and not". I'm about to add another hint to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess:

> Brown.

Going on your pairs hint,

> Brown and letter = Brown + e = brownie!